# Dropdown hover state

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu, hover

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <div class="submenu">something</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
    $j("ul.dropdown li").hover(function () {
        $j(this).addClass("hover");
        $j('div.submenu', this).css('visibility', 'visible').hover(function () {
                $j(this).prev('a').addClass('hover');
            }, function () {
                $j(this).prev('a').removeClass('hover');
            });    
    }, function () {
        $j(this).removeClass("hover");
        $j('div.submenu', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
```

... the menu works fine, but the navigation link (that opens the dropdown) should stay highlighted when on the dropped-down menu. How do I maintain hover state on both the link and the submenu when they're open?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$j("ul.dropdown li").hover(function () {
    $j(this).children('a').andSelf().addClass("hover");
    $j('div.submenu', this).css('visibility', 'visible');
}, function () {
    $j(this).children('a').andSelf().removeClass("hover");
    $j('div.submenu', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

If you don't explicitly need `visibility` and `display` will work, you can do this:

```
$j("ul.dropdown li").hover(function () {
    $j(this).children('a').andSelf().addClass("hover");
    $j('div.submenu', this).show();
}, function () {
    $j(this).children('a').andSelf().removeClass("hover");
    $j('div.submenu', this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but its still the same. As soon as I move away from the link, it returns to normal state.

Comment: I need visibility btw, the whole menu is based on that.

Comment: @Nimbuz - When you say move away, you mean into the submenu, or to a completely different element?

Comment: To the dropped-down submenu, yes.

Comment: Oh, I didn't create the .hover class. Worked great, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`, the page will reserve the visual space that the element should occupy, which typically isn't what is desired with a nested menu

If `visibility` is what you want, ignore me. Otherwise, here's an alternative that uses `display` (that keeps each selected item in the hierarchy highlighted, which seemed to be what your question was asking for):

**Style**

```
li.hover { background: #eee; }
li.hover ul { background: #fff; }
ul ul { display: none; }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li>
        Item 2
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.a</a></li>
            <li>
                Item 2.b
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2.b.1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("ul li").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass("hover").children("ul").show();
        },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass("hover").children("ul").hide();
        }
    );
});
```